# How i can to capture FTP-data packets via tcpdump?

Tags: ftp, tcpdump

When i try to capture FTP packets tcpdump only captures packets which have not text from transmitted .txt file - they are only contains information about my command, directory etc.

I've used this command:

```
tcpdump src x.x.x.x and dst x.x.x.x and port ftp
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
tcpdump 'src x.x.x.x and dst x.x.x.x and (port ftp or ftp-data)'
```

(per http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html )